# Error "ResourceNotFound" occurs when Image.Save() in Shopify API

Tags: python, shopify

Currently, we are registering new products and updating existing products via the Shopify API. However, all of a sudden, we can no longer register new products and the following error is occurring.

`pyactiveresource.connection.ResourceNotFound: Not Found: https://[shop-ulr].myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/images.json`

I am using Python to call ShopifyAPI.
How can I solve this problem?

In order to identify this problem, we checked the code one by one. It seems that the error occurs when the following code is executed.

`image.save()`

```
image = shopify.Image()
image.product_id = product_id
image.src=img['src']
image.alt = img['alt']

...

image.save()   #Error occurred here
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, the cause was actually quite simple.
Indeed, the error occurred with image.save(), but
when I checked the image, it didn't contain any elements.

Furthermore, tracing back the cause, it seems that product.save() was not done correctly,
and it was because there was no product that the image couldn't be set.